# Как привязать к инлайн кнопкам выполнение метода в TelegramBot

Tags: java, telegram-bot

У меня есть метод создания кнопки

```
private InlineKeyboardMarkup createApproveAndRejectButtons() {
        InlineKeyboardButton approveButton = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        approveButton.setText("Принять");
        approveButton.setCallbackData("5");
        InlineKeyboardButton rejectButton = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        rejectButton.setText("Отклонить");
        rejectButton.setCallbackData("6");
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> buttonsRow = new ArrayList<>();
        buttonsRow.add(approveButton);
        buttonsRow.add(rejectButton);
        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> inlineButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        inlineButtons.add(buttonsRow);
        InlineKeyboardMarkup markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        markup.setKeyboard(inlineButtons);
        return markup;
    }
```

И есть метод вывода списка объявлений

```
@SneakyThrows
    private void showAds(String chatId, List<Ad> adList, String role) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        if (chatId.equals(ADMIN_CHAT_ID) && role.equals("ADMIN")) {
            sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(createApproveAndRejectButtons());
        }
        for (Ad ad : adList) {
            sendMessage.setText(
                    ad.getDescription() + "\n"
                            + "Бренд: " + ad.getBrand() + "\n"
                            + "Модель: " + ad.getModel() + "\n"
                            + "Год: " + ad.getYear() + "\n"
                            + "Пробег: " + ad.getMileage() + "\n"
                            + "Цена: " + ad.getPrice() + "\n"
                            + "Телефон для связи: " + ad.getTelephone() + "\n"
            );
            execute(sendMessage);
        }
    }
```

В случае, если я являюсь админом, то показываются кнопки принять или отклонить объявление. И у меня есть готовые методы для изменения статуса объявления и удаления. Но я не понимаю как мне сделать так:

- При нажатии кнопки "Принять" я получаю id объявления для изменения его статуса в бд.
- При нажатии кнопки "Отклонить" я получаю id объявления для удаления из бд.

В двух случаях мне надо получить id. Но я не могу записать в кнопки id, ведь тогда при нажатии любой кнопки я буду получать Id и будет не понятно что я нажал. Как можно это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:
В цикле добавляю `setCallBackData("approve " + ad.getId)` для принятия и `setCallBackData("reject " + ad.getId)` для удаления. После нажатия на одну из кнопок я делаю проверку `if(button.startWith("approve"))` или `if(button.startWith("reject"))`. Потом я делю строку на части и записываю в массив с помощью `String[] buttonText = button.split("\\s")`. Потом просто вызываю нужный метод и в параметры закидываю `buttonText[1]`, где и лежит нужный мне id.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, Вам следует изучить тему **callback-ов**. Благодоря ей вы сможете узнать какая кнопка была нажата.

[Видео на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqyvy6kVgwM), где на практике применяется использование **callback-ов**

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)